# Find out Magento version having only database dump

Tags: database, magento-community, version

My problem is to find out the exact version of Magento (should be one of CE) having only a database dump and no filesystem. So the method with the backend / Mage.php is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

You can get that analyzing 'core_resource' table.

If you will know which sql updates were executed in which version of magento.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried to determine the version by checking the versions in core_resource. Unfortunately there are only versions of different modules and nothing indicating the Magento version directly. My first idea was to search for a list of core_resource's versions which will indicate to the Magento version, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Pretty much the way it is. There isn't any strict module versioning that you could go off of to determine the Magento Install version. I find it kind of annoying.

Comment: its the perfect solution, as every magento version has specific module versions, which are represented in core_resource table.

Comment: @Flyingmana I don't see the modules represented in core_resouce. And I think it makes no sense as some modules do not require any database data. (e.g. Lib_Js_Mage)

Comment: I just did an update from CE 1.7 to CE 1.9.1 and it's just not possible to do any conclusions for the actual Magento version from the core_resource table. For example: catalogsearch_setup before update: 1.6.0.0, after update: 1.8.2.0. And that's the highest version number from any of the magento core resources. (there are other version entries from extensions with higher numbers.)